# CSS get the first div to place last, if media all

Tags: css

When I look at this code in a webbrowser it show the div's just fine.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2 white">
<div class="col-md-2 white80">
<div class="col-md-8 white">
<div class="col-md-8 white">
</div>
</div>
```

But when I look at it on a phone or tablet, it place the first div `col-md-2`the wrong place, I want this div to be showed last.

Is there a way to do this in CSS ?

Comment: You might be able to pull this off with CSS media queries if all the columns were floated you apply a "clear" rule in CSS but I'm betting that would screw up your positioning.  I'm pretty sure it can't be done with CSS because it requires DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the structure of your divs like so:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="wrapper">
         <div class="col-md-2 white80"></div>
         <div class="col-md-8 white"></div>
         <div class="col-md-8 white"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-2 white"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Then in your media queries for your large screen, you float the wrapper right and the last col-md-2 left (giving you your current effect) and then for smaller screens you can just remove the floats

Answer (score 0):

You html markup is wrong, It should be like this:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 white"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2 white80"></div>
  <div class="col-md-8 white"></div>
  <div class="col-md-8 white"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And if you want the col-md-2 the last should be like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 white80"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8 white"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8 white"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 white"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hi Luis
The HTML makeup i right when I look at it on a mac/pc, but when its a tablet/phone responsiv design, then i want the div to be showed last.

Comment: This is new...responsive way...you must use media queries and adapt the way you want

Answer (score 0):

Try this this code in your bootstrap code.
You can modify.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-3">Secon</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">First</div>
</div>
```